# Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource on site with an actionFunction

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I am getting the below error on a Visualforce page when clicking a button which triggers an actionFunction:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://cortexfull-auscript.cs89.force.com/portal/accountregister?refURL=http%3A%2F%2Fcortexfull-auscript.cs89.force.com%2Fportal%2Forder.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://cortexfull-auscript.cs89.force.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

It seems quite weird to me because both origin and requested url are seem to be on the same domain: 
[image]

And the code for that is pretty simple as well.

```
$("#regDivId").live('click',function(){
    registerJun();
});

<apex:actionFunction name="registerJun" action="{!registerUser}" reRender="registerOpt,errorOPT" />
```

I don't think I need to post the controller side code because it is never reached. No debug log is generated when I click that button.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origins are different; your request is to https, and the origin is http. Are you able to access the site through https?